# C++ solution Conversion from VS2003 to VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, clr, visual-studio-2003

I'm just getting back into C++ after a bunch of years away. I'm worried I might be muddling things rather than helping. I've got a VS2003 solution I need to upgrade to VS2010. When I compiled it, I got a whole slew of errors and among them was a warning that the /clr:oldsyntax option was being deprecated. So I compiled under /clr and got less errors. But now I can't link to other existing solutions, mostly due to LNK2019 and LNK2028 errors. I'm trying to call functions that require wchar_t* and wchar_t** arguments. I stopped getting the linking errors when I changed my new code, under the /clr option to use String^ and array^ arguments, but now I can't get it to compile any more because it says it can't convert from array^ to wchar_t*. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I should have had this done already, but I'm now at the point where I seem to just be spinning my wheels.

Comment: The ^ pointers are from C++/CLI or "managed C++" on the .NET platform. You may wish to stay within regular C++ and pointers. It's possible some files got renamed, definitions moved... Even more so between 2003 and 2010 the way to specify include/library directories changed (now it's a project property, rather than global VS setting).

Comment: Thanks, I'm scrapping that method, it seemed like it was worth a shot. I just reworked the question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106275/linking-errors-when-upgrading-a-vs2003-solution-in-c